# Crystal Report prints blank page in newest Chrome 65 or Firefox 58 in ASP.NET Web Forms Application

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, firefox, dom, crystal-reports

I have a piece of javascript code that is supposed to print out a .pdf content from Crystal Report.

```
function onPrintPickRPT() {
     var dvReport = document.getElementById("dvReport");
     var frame1 = dvReport.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
     if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Internet Explorer") != -1) {
          frame1.name = frame1.id;
          window.frames[frame1.id].focus();
          window.frames[frame1.id].print();
     } else {
          var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
          frameDoc.print();
     }
}
```

We are using Crystal Report version 13.0.7

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

and

```
<div class="hidden" id="dvReport">
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="crPick" runat="server" EnableDatabaseLogonPrompt="false" EnableParameterPrompt="false" AutoDataBind="false" />
</div>
```

on the .aspx file

These codes used to work on previous version of chrome or firefox prior to chrome version 65 and possibly firefox 59.

I have downloaded a chrome 43 https://superuser.com/questions/1225990/where-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-google-chrome and disabled its update via services.msc. The chrome 43 ran the code and displayed the pdf report fine.

This has been a problem since March where chrome auto-updates to newest version. Now chrome or firefox only prints a blank page. The only browser that still works is Edge, even Internet Explorer does not work correctly anymore.

And I suspect that the code that causes this is:

```
var frameDoc = frame1.contentWindow ? frame1.contentWindow : frame1.contentDocument.document ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
```

But I have recently debugged this .js with chrome 43 (which works) and newest firefox 59. But the values of the var frameDoc were the same, both contains 'Window'. I am not very sure of all this .js and Crystal Report yet.

Can someone perhaps help me pinpoint the problem and guide to fix this ? Perhaps the newest browser updates / settings breaks this feature ?

=====update 2 days later

I further debugged this problem. I bypassed the onPrintPickRPT() .js function on top to directly show the div#dvReport. I removed the class="hidden".

For the chrome 43 it shows the crystal report fine. For other newest browser it still shows a blank / empty page.

I further inspected element for both cases. The chrome 43 shows a valid iframe containing a new HTML content corresponding to the Crystal Report content. I can't view source it (the iframe is not contained there), but I can inspect source it, idk why. I am using ASP.NET Web Forms.

```
<iframe id="bobjid_1522998310755_iframe" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" margin="0" style="display: block;"> ...valid HTML containing the Crystal Report... </iframe>
```

The newest firefox 59 shows an almost blank iframe with empty html body etc.

```
<iframe id="grabIframe_ContentPlaceHolder1_crPick__UI_leftPanelResizeGrabber" name="grabIframe_ContentPlaceHolder1_crPick__UI_leftPanelResizeGrabber" style="display:none;left:0px;position:absolute;top:0px" src="crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/../dhtmllib/images/skin_standard/../../empty.html" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"> ... </iframe>
```

I noticed that the `src` attribute is `...empty.html` I am confused as why / what may have produced this ?

The .cs codebehind code that initiate the Report is :

```
PickingDataSet ds = new PickingDataSet();

//Data Set Header
ds.PickHeader.Rows.Add(objHeader.PickNo, Convert.ToDateTime(objHeader.ShipmentDate).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy"), objHeader.MerchantName);

//Data Set Detail
for (int i = 0; i < DetailList.Count; i++)
{
    ds.PickDetail.Rows.Add(DetailList[i].ItemNo, DetailList[i].Description, Math.Round(DetailList[i].RequestQty, 2), DetailList[i].CodeUOM, DetailList[i].WHCategoryCode);
}

ReportDocument objReport = new ReportDocument();
objReport.Load(Server.MapPath("~\\Report\\PickingRPT.rpt"));
objReport.SetDataSource(ds);

crPick.Visible = true;
crPick.ReportSource = objReport;
crPick.RefreshReport();
crPick.SeparatePages = false;
crPick.DataBind();
```

I am confused now as how to further debug / pinpoint the problem. Is iframe support somewhat changed in newest browsers?

Comment: I have tried updating to Crystal Reports version 13_0_22 (the latest as of April 2018) and tried it on Firefox 58.0.1, but it still prints blank page (the iframe contains only a blank html). We are all confused why and thinking of using/creating alternatives from crystal report.

Comment: The chrome update to version 66 solves this problem. Still idk why..